# In Linux, how to make a jar file a daemon and how to add websocket

Tags: linux, service, jar, websocket

actually I have 2 jars and 1 ini file. In terminal I can run this java application like that :

```
"/usr/java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/java" -cp  "./eSign.jar:sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" ./esign.tubitak.applet.SignApplet /home/ugurcan/Desktop/Linux_sign_test/test.ini
```

And my gui based program works like this. Now; I need to make this program run without any terminal commands like an exe as a session(which runs in backgraound always). Additionally , I need to add a websocket for the server to program makes a connection between the server and the computer which runs the program.

Thank you for your thoughts !!!

Answer (score 0):

To run a command in background you can use:
`nohup COMMAND &`. `nohup` - makes your program immune to terminal hangup, and & runs it in background.

Can't figure out what do you mean 'to add a websocket for the server to program makes a connection between the server and the computer which runs the program'. Websocket support should be added in your application. But without any further detail we can't help you.